# Books for practicing Computational type linear algebra problems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm aware that linear algebra can be studied on two levels. One being computational (matrix approach) and other being abstract(vector approach).

Currently I'm studying matrix approach but I dont find challenging problems on this approach. Is there any book for practicing questions of this level?

I am studying from Gilbert Strang's book but it doesn't have challenging problems.

Comment: Matrix Computations by Golub&Van Loan is a good start where to find nice problems. Or other numerical linear algebra textbooks (Trefethen&Bau, Watkins, Demmel).